# Javascript 'if' conditional not ... conditioning

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements

I'm checking a number of 'read more' links on my blog, and either hiding the link (for the first two posts), or hiding the content and keeping the link.  I'm running the links' `id` attributes through an `if ... else` statement that looks like so:

```
$(document).find('.contentclicker').each(function(){
    var pt = $(this).parent().attr('id');
    if (pt == "postnum1" ||  "postnum2"){
        $(this).hide();
    }
    else{
        $(this).next().hide();
    }

    });
```

Note: There's some jQuery in there, but it's not relevant.  I know from debugging that the `var pt` is being set correctly to post_num_1, post_num_2, etc. - but when it evaluates post_num_3 and so on, it doesn't go to the `else`.  I've tried `==` and `===`, among other things, and I can't figure out what's wrong.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I am pretty sure you cannot do `if (pt == "postnum1" || "postnum2")` in javascript. Try `if (pt == "postnum1" || pt == "postnum2")`. Basically, even if the first conditional of `pt == "postnum1"` were false, it'd treat the second conditional as true which would avoid the `else` clause at the bottom. At least, that's what I think.

Sorry if I misunderstood your question.

Comment: That did it.  Thanks for the rapid reply!

Answer (score 3):

JavaScript is not strictly typed, it means in particular that it gives you some leeway int your data types and always tries to coerce the expression value to the data type it thinks to be your intention.

In your if statement it tries co convert the part after || to boolean and result of conversion of "postnum2" is always true.

I think what you intended was `(pt == "postnum1" || pt == "postnum2")`

Answer (score 2):

The second part of condition "postnum2" always evaluates to true. You have to convert condition to first answer. Also your post says post_num_1, post_num_2, etc, but you are checking for post_num1.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of if `(pt == "postnum1" ||  "postnum2")`

try

```
if ((pt == "postnum1" ) || (pt == "postnum2"))
{
  // something
}
```

Also you can do something in the switch case(as an alternative)

```
switch(pt)
{
 case "postnum1":
 case "postnum2" : $(this).hide(); break;
 default: $(this).next().hide(); break;
}
```